# How do I combine two properties (each has opposite impact) of the data points to filter out the best data point?

Tags: data-structures, dataset, data-science

This question is more logical than programming. My dataset has several data points (you can think the dataset as an `Array` and the data points as it's elements). Each data point is defined by its two properties. For example, if `x` is one of the data points among **X** data points in the dataset, `a` and `b` are the properties or characteristics of `x`. Here, larger the value of `a` (that ranges from `0` to `1`, think it as a probability), `x` has a good chance to be selected. Moreover, larger the value of `b` (think it as any number that is larger than `1`), `x` has the least chance to be selected. Among `X` data points from the **X**, I need to select a data point that has the maximum `a` value and minimum `b` value. Note that there may be some instances when a single data point may not hold both the conditions at the same time. For example, `x` my have the largest `a` value but not the least `b` value at the same time and vice-versa. Hence, I want to combine both `a` and `b` to yield another meaningful weight value that helps me to filter out the right data point from **X**.

If there any mathematical solution to my problem?